# where I can find change log file in cakephp framework files?

Tags: php, cakephp, changelog

I want to see all Bug fix of [cakephp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp) framework. for other php framework Bug fixes are located in change log file in framework, but in cakephp i can't find any changelog file. where i cat find this file?

Comment: Change log of the core files? Just look online: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp - or download the git repo and manually browse the commit history. The changes are also listed @ https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags and in the migration guides: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html A little bit of googling never hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cakephp doesn't have a changelog file in the repository.

You can either browse trough the github versions for a short textual changelog: 
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases

Alternatively you can read the changes in the cakephp news: 
http://cakephp.org/pages/news

Or if  you want see the granular changes you can browse the source code by tags: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.6.6

Answer (score -1):

CakePHP Folder Structure

- bin
- config
- logs
- plugins
- src
- tests
- tmp
- vendor
- webroot
- .htaccess
- composer.json
- index.php
- README.md

***The logs folder normally contains your log files, depending on your [Logging Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging-configuration).***

> Make sure that the tmp and logs folders exist and are writable, otherwise the performance of your application will be severely impacted. In debug mode, CakePHP will warn you, if it is not the case.